# A problem when run tflite model(the result of tflite model is nan)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I trained a model to convert sketch picture to color picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSwjw.png) middle is ground truth, left is original and right is pridiction. This result was ran by model.h5 but there is a wrong result when i run program using model.tflite.

this is my convert code

```
tflite_convert --keras_model_file=G:/pix2pix/generator.h5 --output_file=G:/pix2pix/convert.tflite
```

this is the result ran by model.tflite

```
[[[[nan nan nan] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution about this question. Just change the attribute fused of tf.keras.layers.bn to false. The output is correct.