# Export Pix2Pix generator to tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

I trained a [Pix2Pix](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) generator from the Tensorflow 2.0 tutorial and I exported it in tflite this way :

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(generator)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("facades.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Unfortunately, I have problems that seem to come from **tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization** when I try to infer it.

First, the result of an inference only returns Nan values. This can be resolved by disabling the [fused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60513183/a-problem-when-run-tflite-modelthe-result-of-tflite-model-is-nan) implementation.

Secondly, the BatchNormalization layer behaves differently depending on whether we are in training or prediction. The tutorial [explicitly states](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix#generate_images) to make a prediction in *training=True* mode. I don't know how to do this with the tflite model.

One solution talks about replacing the **BatchNormalization** layer by an **InstanceNormalization**, which can be found in the *tensorflow_addons*.
The conversion to tflite is done without any problem, but there is still a problem with the inference.
when I call invoke on the interpreter it crashes by returning me a SEGFAULT.  According to the stackcall it would come from SquaredDifference operator of the InstanceNormalization layer.

Has anyone managed to convert this TensorFlow 2.0 model into a tflite and infer it correctly ? How ? Thank you.

PS : I would prefer a solution with BatchNormalization because it is a standard layer in Keras and can therefore also work with TensorFlow javascript.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, how did you solve it?